# How translate a C macro who parse token to D?

Tags: d

How i could translate a C macro who parse token to D ?

```
# define _SIZEOF(x) sz_##x
# define SIZEOF(x) _SIZEOF(x)
# define NEXTPTR(p,t)  (((char *) p) + SIZEOF(t))
```

Thanks

Comment: wouldn't that be the same as `# define NEXTPTR(p,t) ((char *)(((t*) p)+1))` (if the `sz_` prefix is the same as `sizeof`)

Comment: The use of the `sz_` prefix makes me think it's not the same as `sizeof`. :(

Answer (score 1):

Wow. That's a hack.

`cast(void*) p + sz_[whichever]`, I'd say? Just unroll it manually ..

Comment: example of use: BYTE eventdata[SIZEOF(xEvent)]; xEvent it is struct xEvent{}

Answer (score 0):

```
template SIZEOF(T) {
  static if (is(T == char))
    enum SIZEOF = sz_char;
  else static if (is(T == ...))
    ...
}

T* NEXTPTR(T)(p) {
  return (((char *) p) + SIZEOF!t)
}
```